# How to account for forces between connected bodies?

Tags: forces, torque

So lets say that I have a system which consists of two 1kg spheres (1 meter radius) which are connected by a massless rod which keeps the centers of the spheres at a fixed distance of, say 10 meters.  This barbell-like system is laying flat on a frictionless plane, and it is affected by gravity.

Let's say that I want to design a control system which will apply forces and torque to the *one* of the spheres such that this control-sphere's center will remain at the same position, while the other sphere is lifted off the plane and swung upward until it sits directly above the other sphere.

i.e. at each point in time, I want to know which forces and torque to apply to the control sphere to keep the control sphere stationary while moving the other sphere in the correct direction.

In order to accomplish this, how would I calculate the forces which must be applied to the control sphere to counteract the forces being applied by the connecting rod?

Comment: That depends on how you move the sphere. If you move it (for example by grabbing it with you hands) in a circular motion up to the point above the other sphere, then that other sphere will never move away from its position. It will only rotate. Could you give more details for the situation?

Comment: Yeah but if I'm doing that, then my hand is applying forces to the sphere to keep it in position right?  This is for a simulation, so I have to produce all the forces myself.

Comment: You will need a force to start the motion. That force cannot come from the stationary sphere. You need something external like your hand. And how much force that hand applies depends on how you want it to move.

Comment: So this is in the context of a simulation, where I can apply a force more or less "by magic" to the sphere.  I guess you could imagine that I am applying the forces using magnets or something like that which do not contact or restrict the sphere in any way.